# How to Compare specific patches of 2 images and highlight the differences using python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, machine-learning, deep-learning

I am new to deep learning and image processing so need help in understanding if there is a way available by which I can compare specific patches of first image and find if those exact patches are available in second image or not. If not then how can I highlight that difference.
for e.g. I have 2 images of a motherboard and from first image I take an image patch that contains a capacitor, I want to find if this same patch of the image is available in the second picture or not and how to highlight it.

I want to solve this query using python

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: You can use `cv::absdiff()`

Comment: I am trying to use cv2 and sift to extract the key points "sift.detectAndCompute"

Comment: Maybe you can add some images? And your code? Maybe you could clarify if the patch could be rotated or a different size or differently lit in the second image?